Run Insert/Update statements into PG DB in PySpark
I want to use below code to run free form INSERT/UDPATE statements using SPARK API.
but command fails every time I try to run with error message:
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o93.load.
: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "INTO"
Any help please
(Note: I cannot use other methods like psycopg2 or jaydebeapi etc).
def run_pg_sql_spark(qry):
url = "jdbc:postgresql://account-name"
spark_pg = SparkSession.builder.appName("pg_db_conn").getOrCreate()
df = spark_pg.read.format("jdbc") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("query", qry) \
    .option("user", "user") \
    .option("password", "pwd") \
    .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
    .load()

run_pg_sql_spark("INSERT INTO table (task_name) values('x')")

I'm going to say form here JDBC to other databases: query ... A query that will be used to read data into Spark. The specified query will be parenthesized and used as a subquery in the FROM clause. I think you are looking for dbtable ... The JDBC table that should be read from or written into. I would suggest reading  the entire linked to content.

You can do insert or update of postgresql tables using pyspark. are you trying to use same function to do both or trying to do it in two separate functions?

using separate functions, insert is fine, I can still use dataframe to write records into the table but not able to run update, it is failing when I am trying to run update (I tried both options dbtable and query). Thanks!

I got a way to fix it, I used PG DB functions.
